# How to align text in discord py

Tags: discord, discord.py

Hello everyone I am writing my bot for discord, I get the values from google sheets, but they are not displayed beautifully. How can I align them so that the name is under the name and the number is under the numbers

Here's how it turns out https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gdquh.png
And it should be like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAPg2.png

```
spreadsheet_id = 'id'
result = service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range='A1:C15', majorDimension='ROWS').execute()
values = result.get('values', [])
embed = discord.Embed(description="\n".join([x[0] + " " + x[2] for x in values]))

result2 = service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range='A16:C28', majorDimension='ROWS').execute()
values2 = result2.get('values', [])
embed2 = discord.Embed(description="\n".join([x[0] + " " + x[2] for x in values2]))
```

Comment: You can use backticks for fixed width font formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been putting my data into pandas DataFrames, so I've been using to_markdown https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_markdown.html and printing it within code blocks.

````
import pandas as pd
array = pd.DataFrame(values)
embed = discord.Embed(description='```' + array.to_markdown(index=False) + '```')
````

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).